How to work with local toast notifications from C# using only Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications.dll
I like to use the built-in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319. I can create local notifications using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications.dll or CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Notifications.dll via Assembly.Load(), GetType() and InvokeMember(). But I can't set the lifetime of the notification. I can't get in touch with my notifications in the notification center to delete the notification without activation. There are no examples anywhere. Is it possible to do this? Can you give me an example like this?
For example, you can display a simple notification like this:
Assembly a = Assembly.Load("Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications");
Type b = a.GetType("Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications.ToastContentBuilder");
dynamic o = new dynamic[2];
o[1] = Activator.CreateInstance(b,
     BindingFlags.CreateInstance|BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.NonPublic,
     null, new object[]{}, null);
o[1].Show();

And how to kill it after 1 minute is not known :-(
Apparently I should take advantage of:
Type m = a.GetType("Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications.ToastNotificationManagerCompat");

To the following intuitively written line:
o[0] = Activator.CreateInstance(m,
     BindingFlags.CreateInstance|BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.NonPublic,
     null, new object[]{}, null);

gives an error - constructor was not found. I understand that I have to open {} and write something there. But what to write is unknown.

Why are you loading the assembly in such a convoluted way? Just add a reference to the package and use the methods. There are no examples quite the opposite, the official docs contain thorough docs and examples

Expiration is specifically covered in Set Expiration Time

Panagiotis Kanavos,
Is there such a package for .net 4.0? As far as I know DotNet packages are downloaded from version 5. Version 4 is installed on Windows by default (I installed only Windows) and is located in the folder C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
Maybe there is a way to include packages in .net 4.0? Can you tell me how to do this?

You aren't using .NET Framework 4.0 in the first place. 4.x runtimes are binary replacements and can't be downgraded. Whatever your OS is using is almost certainly a newer version. If you can use TLS 1.2, which almost every site uses nowadays, you aren't running on .NET 4.0. No matter what the target runtime version of your application is, it's still running on the installed runtime

You'll find the .NET Framework versions bundled in Windows versions here. All supported Windows 10 versions have 4.6.2 at least. All Windows 10 versions, even discontinued ones, used 4.6 at least

Panagiotis Kanavos,
I can't turn on the package, as it is officially written:

I'm Running:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe notifier.net.csproj

The notifier.net.csproj contains:









error MSB4066: unrecognized attribute "Version" in the element .

What are you referring to? Did you actually try to change your project's runtime to a valid .NET 4.x version and use NuGet to add the package? What you wrote suggests that you copied the wrong snippet from the settings page.

I write programs without Visual Studio, in a regular Far text editor. So far I haven't been able to make this line of code work:
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications;

Use the NuGet tool to add the packages then. In the old project format used by .NET Framework 4.0 the package information was stored outside csproj. Although, if there's such confusion about project files, packages and runtimes, you should use a free IDE like Visual Studio Community or Rider Community

Panagiotis Kanavos,
Thank you so much for helping me. I think there really is hardly anyone who can answer my question.... I tried to install Visual Studio. In Visual Studio, I received a message that I want to connect this package to .Net 4.0 is not allowed. I ended up, that I installing .Net 8 and removed Visual Studio. The notification package began to be connected according to the package connection documentation. Thanks again for your helpfulness.
